# Trying to draw connected rectangles

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm trying to draw 3 rectangles on the same y-axis. Each of the rectangles are to be connected by a line.

The rectangles are appearing as I'd like but I can't get the line to appear in the right spot

```
function Point(x,y){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
}
Point.prototype.toPath = function(op) {return op+this.x+','+this.y;};

window.onload = function (){
    paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);

    paper.setStart();
    processes = [
        paper.rect(10, 10, 60, 40),
        paper.rect(110, 10, 60, 40),
        paper.rect(210, 10, 60, 40)
    ];

    p1 = new Point(
        processes[0][0].x.baseVal.value + processes[0][0].width.baseVal.value,
        processes[0][0].y.baseVal.value + (processes[0][0].height.baseVal.value / 2)
    );

    p2 = new Point(
        processes[1][0].x.baseVal.value,
        processes[1][0].y.baseVal.value + (processes[1][0].height.baseVal.value / 2)
    );

    paper.path(p1.toPath('M') + p2.toPath('H'));

    var set = paper.setFinish();
    set.attr({fill: "red"});
};
```

The result I'm expecting is something like

```
  ------         ------
 |      |_______|      |
 |      |       |      |
  ------         ------
```

but I'm getting something like this

```
  ------         ------
 |   ___|_______|      |
 |      |       |      |
  ------         ------
```

*(please ignore my global variables - I'm trying to debug in console and I need them in the global scope)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see, the problem is that `Horizontal Line` command takes only one parameter ([docs](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.path)). As your helper function always provides two parameters, after function evaluation you end up with something like this:

`paper.path('M70,30H110,30');`

Which obviously does not correspond to expected input.

You could change your helper functions to generate something like this:

`paper.path('M70,30H110');`

But in this case simplest solution is to use `Line To` command instead of `Horizontal Line` command (change `H` to `L`). `Line To` takes two arguments. So you would end up with something like this:

`paper.path('M70,30L110,30');`

In your code sample just change `H` to `L`.

```
...
paper.path(p1.toPath('M') + p2.toPath('L'));
...
```

See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DktHL/422/)

Comment: Added extra information about what caused this issue.